# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE with mysql 5.0.8

Tags: mysql, xml

I am working on a test site locally. I am loading an xml file into my database with teh following sql query:

```
    LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/courseInfo18.xml' 
INTO TABLE wp_courses ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Course>' (ReferenceNo, ProviderCode, ProviderName, CourseID, CourseName, 
    CourseTypeID, CourseTypeName, LocationCode, LocationName, StartDate, 
    FinishDate) ;
```

It works fine locally but not on the live site. I have checked the MySQL version of the live site and it is running only 5.0.8 could this be the reason or does anyone know if there is an alterative way to do this on an older version of MySQL.

Thanks in advance,

Donna :)

Comment: No I replaced the C://courseInfo18.xml with the absolute address www.mysite.com/courseInfo18.xml

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay in response!!
I upgraded my version of MySQL to 5.5.32 and this works now.